# Change Color of Text in range cells to White Based on two conditions: 1)Value in cell and 2) Text in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

Conditions for changing font color:

1. If Vapor fraction (2nd column from left)= 1 Then all cells in the table under the column header that contains the word "Liquid" should change font to white.
2. If Vapor fraction=0 Then all cells in the table under the column header that contains the word "Vapor" should change font to white.

There are 6 tables in this sheet and I would like the macro to apply this to all 6 tables.

[image: Image of tables]

Thank you so much for your help.

I tried tackling one column at a time as I don't know how to use loops right now.

[image: Picture of code]

It resulted in nothing happening. I am a novice when it comes to vba..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Plese do not post pictures of code. No one can copy/paste it when it's an image. Instead, just copy/paste the code itself.

Comment: You may benefit from some basic debugging. Use `F9` to put a breakpoint on a stopping point, like your `If` statement, then use `F8` to step line by line and you can then watch what it's doing.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 

Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Please include column and row headers in your screenshots, so we can relate the range addresses in your code to the data on the worksheet.

Comment: Did you consider/try Conditional Formatting?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to evaluate that all cells in the range D2:D17 have the value 1, you can do like this:

```js
Dim VaporFraction As Range
Dim VaporFractionCell As Range
Dim ChangeToWhite As Boolean

ChangeToWhite = True
For Each myCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D17")
 If Not myCell.Value = 1 Then
    ChangeToWhite = False
    Exit For
 End If
Next myCell

If ChangeToWhite = True Then
    'Your code to format to white
End if
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you cannot compare the multiple cell range `.Value` property with a single value. If you want to avoid loop when comparing, you can use the `.Text` property. It returns always a single value.
If all cells in the range have the same values and numberformats `.Text` returns this common value, if different, it returns `Null`.
`If Vaporfraction.Text = 1 Then ...`

Comment: Not sure if this answer is correct. `Range("A1").Value` will return a single value, no need of text. Do you mean is not correct to use `.value` if the range got more than 1 cell?

Comment: Of course it is valid for multiple cell ranges. I thought this was obvious in the context of the question and the code presented.